# Jquery Auto Complete isn't working. What have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have done is,

*Ajax call return a combined **value***. 
*I **split** and store them in a **array***.
*I Give it to **jquery auto-complete***
but it isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function Search_Items()
    {
    var action             =     "Search_Item";
    $.ajax({
            method:'GET',
            url:'ajax_process.php',
            data: {action:action},
            success:function(result)
            {
                document.getElementById("Search_Result_Div").innerHTML=result;
                var temp=document.getElementById("Search_Result").value;
                availableProducts=temp.split("`");

                $(function() {
                    var Product=$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                      source: availableProducts,
                    select: function (event,ui) {Load_Products(ui.item.value);}
                    });
                  });   

            }
        });
    };


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tags").click(function() { $(this).select(); $('#ui-id-1').css('max-height','300px');$('#ui-id-1').css('overflow','auto');$('#ui-id-1').css('font-size','13px');} );
    });
    </script>
```

This is a HTML tag which is meant to be auto-complete,

```
<input type="text" class="product_input" style="width:100px;"   id='tags'>
```

NOTE:

- Value returned from ajax is perfect.
- I've checked the array value after split. It's fine.
- jquery version: jquery-1.10.2.min.js
- variable 'availableProducts' declared globally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
$(function() {
  var Product=$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableProducts,
   select: function (event,ui) {Load_Products(ui.item.value);}
   });
 });
```

with

```
  var Product=$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableProducts,
   select: function (event,ui) {Load_Products(ui.item.value);}
   });
```

I don't know why you are using your code inside

```
$(function() {

});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/
as it stands for document ready which you have already written below.So try without it.

Comment: Can you explain (so that your answer is more complete, especially for us JavaScript newbies) why that change would make a difference?

Comment: You are right. Document ready doesn't require in that location. But that's not the reason for the problem. I've tried by removing that thing. doesn't work out. I'm rewriting entire code. hope that works.